# How do I write String arrays to a text file in java using Printwriter?

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, text

I need help writing some contents of array objects (following are two example of arrays I'm using) to a text file using Printwriter. Any ideas? I'm a beginner, so the simpler the better, thanks!

```
Astronauts[0][0] = new Passengers(-1, "", 1, 0, 0, "", "", 0, "", "", "", "", ""); 

Astronauts[0][1] = new Passengers(0, "Pilot", 2424, 14, 0, "Bruce", "Banner", 0, "678-884-6325", "Mom", "678-884-6323","","");

Astronauts[0][2] = new Passengers(0, "Pilot", 1248, 3, 0, "Sally", "Forth", 0, "678-921-1135", "Hannah", "678-921-1130","","");


 Astronauts[1][0] = new Passengers(-1, "", 2, 0, 0, "", "", 0, "", "", "", "", "");

Astronauts[1][1] = new Passengers(0, "Pilot", 1022, 55, 0, "Buz", "Aldrin", 0, "404-014-4553", "June", "404-014-4555","","");

Astronauts[1][2] = new Passengers(0, "Pilot", 2813, 8, 0, "Alice", "Dyer", 0, "678-884-6325", "Mom", "678-884-6323","","");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your array contents are all of the same class `Passengers`, if you're not happy with the default Array.toString format I'd create a `toString()` method in `Passengers` that returns your desired string representation.

Then:

```
try {
       PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));

       for(Passengers[] passengers: Astronauts) {
           for(Passengers passenger: passengers) {
                printWriter.println(passenger);
           }
       }

       printWriter.close();  // no need to flush, since close() does it anyway.

   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Note: As others have mentioned, I'd rename the `Astronauts` variable to be lowercase `astronauts`. I'd also rename the `Passengers` class to `Passenger`.

Edit: Using the above code the output file should appear in the working directory where you are running the program from. Alternatively you can supply a full file path such as `C:/Users/Me/directory/output.txt` but in that case you need to make sure the directory path already exists.

Yet another alternative is to modify the code to automatically create the path for you:

```
    File file = new File ("C:/Users/Me/directory/output.txt");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
```

Comment: ok, so I used this code but adapted it to the whole file and I'm still not seeing a text file. Shouldn't one pop up on its own?

Comment: Yes the above code should create the file for you. I've edited the answer with some explanation in this regard. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I'm catching your problem correctly, because writing the contents of an array to a file is pretty straight-forward:

```
String[] arr = {"a", "b", "c"};
try {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
    pw.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    pw.flush();
    System.out.println("Finished");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**[EDIT]**

I realise I may not have addressed your entire problem. If you are wondering how to write the desired traits of the *objects* contained in an array, you can override the [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method of your custom class:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B[] bs = {new B("a", "b"),
                  new B("c", "d"),
                  new B("e", "f"),
                  new B("g", "h")};

        try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
            for (B b : bs) {
                pw.println(b);
            }
            pw.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}

class B {
    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;

    public B (String prop1, String prop2) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.prop1 + " " + this.prop2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`PrintWriter` admits a `String`, so you can override `toString()` method in `Astronauts` class, and then iterate over 1-D or 2-D dimenssional array:

By the way, variable names should start with lowercase character.

- 1-D

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < astronauts.length; i++) { 
      pw.print(Arrays.toString(astronauts[i]); 
  }
  ```
- 2-D

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < astronauts.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < astronauts[i].length; i++) {
          pw.print(astronauts[i][j]); 
      } 
  }
  ```

Don't forget to `flush()` and `close()` `PrintWriter`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you might want to do it.

```
String twoDArray[][] = {{"one","two"},{"one","two"},{"one","two"}};
    String filePath = "C:/Users/arjun.lajpal/Desktop/dummyFile.txt";
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(filePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    writer.printf("%20s%20s","Astraunauts","Passengers");
    writer.println();
    for(int i=0;i<twoDArray.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<twoDArray[i].length;j++)
            writer.printf("%20s",twoDArray[i][j]);

        writer.println();

        }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

This not only will make your file but also write to the file in a nice tabular format without any need to override toString() method.